# I want to search a field but use partial text to locate record. Code now finds record but I have to enter entire text for record to be found. Access

Tags: ms-access-2016

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
On Error Resume Next

    Dim strNDetails As String
    Dim strSearch As String
    
'Check txtSearch for Null value or Nill Entry first.

    If IsNull(Me![txtSearch]) Or (Me![txtSearch]) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a value!", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Search Criterion!"
        Me![txtSearch].SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------
        
'Performs the search using value entered into txtSearch
'and evaluates this against values in strStudentID
        
    DoCmd.ShowAllRecords
    DoCmd.GoToControl ("NDetails")
    DoCmd.FindRecord Me!txtSearch
        
    NDetails.SetFocus
    NDetails = NProvider.Text
    txtSearch.SetFocus
    strSearch = txtSearch.Text
        
'If matching record found sets focus in strStudentID and shows msgbox
'and clears search control

    If NDetails Like "*" = strSearch Then
        MsgBox "Match Found For: " & strSearch, , "Congratulations!"
        NDetails.SetFocus
        txtSearch = ""
        
    'If value not found sets focus back to txtSearch and shows msgbox
        Else
           MsgBox "Match Not Found For: " & strSearch & " - Please Try Again.", _
            , "Invalid Search Criterion!"
            txtSearch.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
If NDetails Like "*" & strSearch & "*" Then
```